# Is there a strong case for the existence of languages that lack a clear morpho-syntactic distinction between nouns and verbs?

Tags: verbs, nouns, morphosyntax

Is there a strong case for the existence of languages that lack a clear morpho-syntactic distinction between nouns and verbs?   If so, what would be an example of a phrase structure for a uniclausal simple transitive sentence in such a language?  For instance, what would be the phrase structure of a sentence in one such language which sentence translates as "The boy ate the burger"?

Comment: I think that the example sentence you ask for is not especially interesting w.r.t. a language that lacks a distinction between verbs and nouns (as parts of speech): because different constituents of a sentence can still be marked by different inflections, can't they? Or do you mean something different than no distinction of verbs and nouns as parts of speech (i.e., no classification of stems) by "no morpho-syntactic distinction between nouns and verbs"? Could u please explain your notion with more details then(because at least me has tended to think of the distinction between parts of speech)?

Comment: The discssuion [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/280/363) may be relevant.

Comment: See also **[What's the global difference between nouns and verbs?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/763/whats-the-global-difference-between-nouns-and-verbs)** and **[Is it possible to analyse Māori grammar without contrasting nouns and verbs?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/536/is-it-possible-to-analyse-mori-grammar-without-contrasting-nouns-and-verbs)**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every language seems to distinguish between the same basic syntactic *functions*. For instance, we can distinguish between *predicates* and *arguments* within a sentence, or between a *head* and its *modifiers* in a smaller phrase.

Now, in English, most words are limited as to which function they can play.  Nouns like "boy" make good arguments, but they don't make good predicates on their own: you have to tack on a copula (e.g. "be a boy").  Verbs like "ate" make good predicates but they don't make good arguments on their own: you have to build a relative clause around them first (e.g. "the one who ate").  So we can say this:

> [The boy]<sub>Arg</sub> [ate]<sub>Pred</sub>

But sentences like these, intended to mean something like "The one who ate is a boy," are ungrammatical:

> [The ate]<sub>Arg</sub> [boy]<sub>Pred</sub>
>
> [The ate]<sub>Arg</sub> [boy-s]<sub>Pred</sub>

This limitation is clear evidence for a morphosyntactic noun/verb distinction in English.

Okay.  So there are *claimed* to be languages without this limitation: languages, that is, in which any word can take any syntactic function. The Salishan language family is the classic source for examples of this.  Here's one example from St'át'imcets: in *this* sentence, *t'ak* 'go' is the predicate...

> [T'ak]<sub>Pred</sub> [ti=nk'yáp=a]<sub>Arg</sub>
>
> [go]<sub>Pred</sub> [DET=coyote=DET]<sub>Arg</sub>
>
> "Coyote goes along"

...and in *this* one, *nk'yap* '[be a] coyote' is the predicate:

> [nk'yáp]<sub>Pred</sub> [ti=t'ak=a]<sub>Arg</sub>
>
> [coyote]<sub>Pred</sub> [DET=go=DET]<sub>Arg</sub>
>
> "The one going along is Coyote"

(Note that the word order is backwards from English: Salishan predicates come at the start of the clause, before their subjects.)

So people have *claimed*, based on data like these, that there is no noun/verb distinction in Salishan languages.

The trouble is, in all the Salish languages where people have checked, it turns out that there are other morphosyntactic asymmetries between nouns and verbs.  For instance, in St'át'imcets, only nouns can be the head of a relative clause.  You can say this...

> [ti=tupun-táli=ha]<sub>Modifier</sub> [sqaycw]<sub>Head</sub>
>
> [DET=hit-3sg=DET]<sub>Modifier</sub> [man]<sub>Head</sub>
>
> "The man who hit him"

but *not* this...

> [ti=sqaycw=a]<sub>Modifier</sub> [tupun-as]<sub>Head</sub>
>
> [DET=man=DET]<sub>Modifier</sub> [hit-3sg]<sub>Head</sub>
>
> lit. "The him-hitter who mans"

(Once again, the St'át'imcets word order is the reverse of the English word order: the modifier comes first, before the head.)

So if you want to describe the syntax of relative clauses in St'át'imcets, you *do* need a noun/verb distinction after all.  And this seems to be the case for the other Salishan languages as well, though the jury is still out on some of them.  [This handout by Seth Cable is a good place to start for information on the noun/verb distinction in Salishan (and also Wakashan) languages](http://people.umass.edu/scable/PNWSeminar/handouts/Lex/Lexical-Categories.pdf), and the references in it go into more detail.  (The St'át'imcets examples here are all from Cable's handout.)

So okay, the Salishan languages have a noun/verb distinction.  What about other language families?  I'm less familiar with the literature here.  Some people have made similar claims about Austronesian languages.  David Gil, for instance, claims that Riau Indonesian has no noun/verb distinction.  But [here's a paper by Brendon Yoder arguing against Gil's conclusions](http://www.und.nodak.edu/dept/linguistics/wp/2010Yoder.pdf), claiming that Riau Indonesian does have a noun/verb distinction after all.

Long story short: In the cases I'm familiar with where someone has said "Language X lacks a noun/verb distinction," further study has suggested that their claim was dubious our outright wrong.  We still can't be dead certain that all languages have the distinction.  But it would be a big surprise at this point to find a language that really and truly lacked it.

Comment: Samoan (along with several other Austronesian languages) seems to be the best example of a language where a noun/verb distinction is difficult to establish, which has led to the idea of Samoan lexemes as 'precategorial'.

Comment: Yes I've read the same about Hawaiian and also read that it could be applicable both to cover Polynesian language, and to cover Austronesian languages.

Comment: Those claims are controversial too, though I'm less well read on that literature.  Section 3 in this article gives evidence against the 'precategorical' claim in Tongan and Samoan: http://www.ualberta.ca/~dbeck/FlexDist.pdf

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be no natural language with just one word class for both nouns and verbs. Although some Philippine-type Austronesian languages like Tagalog are said to have no noun/verb distinction, it seems what they have is weak distinction instead.

According to [Himmelmann](http://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/allgemeine_sprachwissenschaft/dozenten-unterlagen/himmelmann/lexcat.pdf),

> With regard to syntactic categories it may be argued that all Tagalog
>   content words (both roots and derived words) are categorially
>   indistinct, i.e. they may all occur in essentially the same basic
>   syntactic positions (section 3.1)

but [Kroeger](http://www.gial.edu/images/pdf/Kroeger-reply-Foley-LFG98.pdf) disputes this saying

> The distributional similarities mentioned above between nouns and
>   verbs in Tagalog apply equally to adjectives and even PPs.  Each of
>   the four categories may appear as (i) a clausal predicate, (ii) a
>   modifier within the NP, or (iii) a noun phrase..[but]..this difference
>   between verbal and non-verbal clauses provides a clear distributional
>   test for distinguishing between verbs and all other lexical
>   categories: ***only a verb can function as the predicate of a verbal
>   clause***.

According to Himmelmann,

> With regard to lexical categories, however, there are clear-cut
>   categorial distinctions (section 3.2).

His conclusion:

> An important aspect of the voice system in Tagalog is the fact that voice-marked words (V-words) as well as the roots from which they are derived ***belong to lexical categories which are very different from the lexical categories found in more familiar languages such as English***. It has been repeatedly suggested that the difference 
>   pertains to the fact that Tagalog roots are precategorial and/or that there is no distinction between nouns and verbs in Tagalog. The preceding sections present a somewhat different explication of the difference between the two systems of lexical categories and its repercussions for the voice systems. Specifically, it is claimed that 
>   Tagalog roots are generally not bound and/or precategorial roots. Instead, Tagalog roots belong to different morpho-lexical classes. That is, it cannot be predicted solely on the basis of their meaning with which affixes a given root may occur. Furthermore, all kinds of roots, including roots denoting ACTIONS, allow for unaffixed uses. In their unaffixed uses, roots may denote THINGS, ANIMATE BEINGS, PROPERTIES, STATES, RESULTS OF
>   ACTIONS, NAMES OF ACTIONS, etc., i.e. concepts which in English are generally rendered by nouns or adjectives.
>   What roots cannot denote is the actual and specific performance of an action. Only V-words may denote the actual performance of an action. In this regard, Tagalog V-words are similar to English verbs. They differ, however, from English verbs in the following important respects:
>
> - While Tagalog V-words clearly belong to their own morpho-lexical category, they do not belong to a special  terminal syntactic
>     category. That is, V-words have morphological and semantic properties
>     which set them  apart from all other Tagalog content words. But with
>     regard to the positions they may occupy in a phrase  structure tree
>     they do not differ from other content words. In English, on the other
>     hand, there is an  unambiguous correlation between (morpho-)lexical 
>     and terminal syntactic categories: Membership in a given  lexical
>     (sub-)category implies membership in a specific terminal syntactic
>     category (‘die’ is an intransitive  verb, and hence a verb and not a
>     noun).
> - All Tagalog V-words are necessarily derived, while in English there are both basic and derived verbs. The  derivation of Tagalog V-words
>     is manifest both formally and semantically: Formally, the
>     morpho-lexical  category of the root is changed to the
>     morpho-lexical category of V-words. Semantically, an oriented action
>     expression is derived from an expression which denotes a THING, STATE,
>     NAME OF AN ACTION, RESULT OF AN  ACTION, etc. The notion oriented
>     action expression conveys two things: First, oriented action
>     expressions  denote the actual performance of an action (and not the
>     name or the result of an action). Second, they denote  the actual
>     performance of an action in such a way that at the same time they also
>     denote one of the  participants involved in the action.
> - For English verbs active voice is the basic, non-derived voice. For Tagalog V-words all voices are derived in  the same way. Hence, it
>     does not make sense to consider one of the four Tagalog voices the
>     basic voice.

Comment: Very enlightening!